# Remove topics list from minutes

Tags: packages, minutes

I'm using the minutes package to create meeting minutes, but I do not want the list of topics it generates at the beginning.
I have looked through the documentation but I don't understand big parts of it.
I'm using it with the scrartcl document class, but am willing to use a different document class if necessary.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Title}
\maketitle

\topic{First example topic}
\topic{Second example topic}

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It would really help things out if you could provide a minimal working example.  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style with:

```
\minutesstyle{contents=false}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}

\minutesstyle{contents=false} %%%%%% <<<  here <<<<<
\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Title}
\maketitle

\topic{First example topic}
\topic{Second example topic}
  
\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not completely clear to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\min@listoftopicsfalse
\makeatother
\begin{Minutes}{Title}
\maketitle
\topic{First example topic}
\topic{Second example topic}
\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

is it what you want?